# can't determine number of catergories in trainImageCategoryClassifier in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Doing this example in Matlab [Image Category Classification](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-computer-vision/mw/vision_product-ImageCategoryClassificationExample-image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features) I have found an error trying to encode an image into a feature vector.

`categoryClassifier = trainImageCategoryClassifier(trainingSet, bag);`

> Error using imageCategoryClassifier (line 436)
>   You need at least two image categories. That means that the number of elements in input array of imageSet
>   objects, imSets, must be at least two.
>
> Error in imageCategoryClassifier.create (line 328)
>               this = imageCategoryClassifier(imgSet, bag, varargin{:});
>
> Error in trainImageCategoryClassifier (line 82)
>       classifier = imageCategoryClassifier.create(imgSet, bag, varargin{:});

i have 3 categories But it says i have one category in trainingSet. what should i do?!

Comment: which method did you use to generate `traningSet`? did you use `splitEachLabel`?

Comment: yes,
`[trainingSet, validationSet] = splitEachLabel(imds, 0.3, 'randomize');`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MATLAB are you using? This documentation is for the 2017a version. If you have an older version then running this code from the document gives you a 3x1 vector of categories.That is why the classifier treats it as one category.For 3 categories you'll need a 1x3 vector.

You can go to the command window and open the reference page on imageCategoryClassifier or on bagOfFeatures.This will give you the documentation of the version that you're running. There'll also be a link for the example MATLAB program. That's what worked for me.

Hope this helps!